# Method in app Delegate

Tags: ios, xcode, methods, delegates

iOS apps will have a class that adopts the UIApplicationDelegate, called something like xxxAppDelegate.

Which method from the protocol is most commonly implemented in the XXXappdelegate class? Is the implementation required or optional? What would you use it for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The application delegate is the entry point for your application as far as you, the developer, are concerned. The application delegate is notified of major changes in your particular instance of `UIApplication`. By far the most commonly used method is `-application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`. This method is where you create your initial view controller and add it to the window.

With all of the application templates provided by Xcode 4, you'll see that an application delegate is created for you with many of the common methods stubbed in.

Comment: That is awesome.  Thank you.  Is the implementation required? If you don't doesn't it just load a blank view? What would you use it for? Creating a custom view? Thanks